# UIImageView frame not animating as expected (size and origin)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

Ran into an issue with a UIView frame animation. The view should animate in both origin and size, with the size increasing and origin moving linearly to keep the view in the same place. But what happens is, the view decreases to size (0,0) and then increases to a size that is still not the correct one. See attached video.

Video of the issue: https://media.pairby.com/I/u/a/IualExcJXn7CqLsGkcNZfwyEw5MKi3SV/v.mp4

```
func animateIn() {
  // Make _iconView large
  let w = bounds.width
  _iconView.frame = CGRect(
    x: frame.midX - w/2,
    y: frame.midY - w/2,
    width: w, height: w)

  isHidden = false

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.alpha = 1

    // Animate it smaller
    let w = self.bounds.width * 0.5
    self._iconView.frame = CGRect(
      x: self.frame.midX - w/2,
      y: self.frame.midY - w/2,
      width: w, height: w)
  })
}

func animateOut() {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
    self.alpha = 0

    // Make it large again
    let w = self.bounds.width
    self._iconView.frame = CGRect(
      x: self.frame.midX - w/2,
      y: self.frame.midY - w/2,
      width: w, height: w)

  }, completion: { _ in self.isHidden = true })
}
```

More details:

`self` is a subclass of UIView, constrained to a superview.

`_iconView` is a `UIImageView`

`animateIn` is guaranteed to run before `animateOut`

`animateOut` is the function that does not work as expected, `animateIn` works

Comment: I think your forgetting the fact that because you halved the width before the animation 's' is actually equal to half of what you thought (the origional size). so it returns to only half the size that you expect

Comment: Is `_iconView` a `UIImageView`, with an "X" image? Is `self` the "main view" or a subclassed `UIView`? Are you trying to "grow" the X to the full width of the view, and have it fade out to transparent?

Comment: Hey, @torinpitchers. I have not halved the width of the superview (self). I use the superview's bounds when doing the calculations.

Comment: @DonMag I added more details to the original post. `self` is a subclass of UIView and `_iconView` is a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what all you need to do, however...

1. You do not need to change the size to begin with - you can simply animate the _iconView frame from its current state, and
2. because _iconView is a *subview* of `self`, you need to position it relative to the bounds, not the frame.

Try it like this:

```
func doAnim() -> Void {     

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0

        let s = self.bounds.width
        let halfS = s / 2

        self._iconView.frame = CGRect(
            x: self.bounds.midX - halfS,
            y: self.bounds.midY - halfS,
            width: s,
            height: s)

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing all `_iconView` related code from the `layoutSubviews()` function. I am not sure why it was getting called in the first place.